# Saving and accessing API results in a variable in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension that pulls a large amount of data from an API and uses it to modify content on a page. Because the amount of data is so large, I'd like to be able to save it once in the browser and be able to access it instead of doing an API call each time a page loads.

It's my understanding this can be done by putting the API call in the background page and then calling the variable from the background page in the content script. I've also tried storing the data in local storage. Neither method is working for me and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

In my code in the background page, I have the API results stored in a variable. I'm calling it in the content script like this:

```
var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
var myData = background.APIData; //where APIData is the variable I set in the background page
```

My attempt to use local storage looks like this:

```
//Background page
chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': APIData}, function() {
      // Notify that we saved.
      console.log('APIData saved to storage');
    });

//Content script
var myData = localStorage["APIData"];
```

As of this moment, the extension isn't even loading in the page using the code where I'm trying to access local storage. The extension will load with the other method but the data doesn't seem to be there. I know my API call is working because the extension works when I put it all in the content script. But that creates the problem where I'm calling the API each time the page loads. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Examine your code closely. You are setting the data to two different bins.

First, you call **chrome.storage.sync.set** and set "value" to the value of *APIData*.

Second, you call **localStorage**['APIData'] which refers to a separate storage bin and property name.

Two solutions here, the first being the preferred way to set/get persistent data in a Chrome extension:

A1) set it with **chrome.storage.sync.set**( { value:data } )

A2) get it with **chrome.storage.sync.get**( null, function( storage ){ storage.value } )

B1) set it with **localStorage**.value = data

B2) get it with **localStorage**.value

Comment: This still isn't working for me? Modified my code as below
//background page
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'value': myData}, function() {
          // Notify that we saved.
          console.log('myData saved to storage');
        });
    //content script
    var someData = chrome.storage.sync.get( null, function( storage ){   storage.myData } );

Comment: Make sure you have the "storage" permission set in your manifest.json file.

Comment: Yes, I do: "permissions": ["storage","tabs","activeTab","<all_urls>", "*://*/*"]

Comment: Your last permission is a duplicate of <all_urls>, try removing that. I don't think it will have an impact but it couldn't hurt to do so. As a next step, I would try using chrome.storage.local instead of chrome.storage.sync and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @SteveB Please note that inline code should be formatted with backticks on SO: `\`code\``

Comment: Also, there's an issue with you recommending to use `localStorage` still: this won't work in a content script (since the origin is different)